# Turtle Graphics with non-linear characters

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am currently trying to write a Python program that includes the letter X, and numbers 3 and 5. To be exact, "X35S"

I am trying to NOT use the turtle.write function and instead use solely commands. Currently, my code reads:

```
import turtle

turtle.down ( )
turtle.color("red")
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.pensize(7)

turtle.right (45)
turtle.forward (70)
turtle.backward (140)
turtle.forward (70)
turtle.left (90)
turtle.forward (70)
turtle.backward (140)
```

But I am unsure how to draw a 5, 3, or S (I struggle with the non-straight lines). Thank you!

Comment: use shorter lines and smaller angles to get smoother part of  circle. It means you will have to draw more lines - but with `for`-loop it not so hard.

Answer (score 0):

To draw smoother rounding elements you have to draw more shorter lines with smaller angles.
But with `for`-loop it is not problem. I show it on circle.

```
import turtle

def circle(parts=360, line=1):
    for x in range(parts):
        turtle.forward(line)
        turtle.left(360/parts)

def move():
    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.down()

turtle.tracer(False)

circle(6, 360/6)
move()
circle(10, 360/10)
move()
circle(20, 360/20)
move()
circle(30, 360/30)
move()
circle(360, 360/360)

turtle.update()
```

[image]

Similar with half circle

```
import turtle

def halfcircle(parts=360, line=1, direction=1):
    for x in range(parts//2):
        turtle.forward(line)
        turtle.left(360/parts * direction)

turtle.tracer(False)

for x in range(2):
    halfcircle(20, 360/30, 1)
    halfcircle(20, 360/30, -1)

turtle.update()
```

[image]